# How to use masked inputs in Keras?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I am beginner of Machine Learning and Keras. I have a reference code of
Keras. But its style is old and not supported in latest keras.
So I want to reproduce this reference code. But I am not sure how to use a
mask.
Old style code uses 'inputs' and 'merge_mode', so how do I realize this in latest keras?

- keras 1.2.2
- Python 3.5.2 (Anaconda 4.1.1, 64bit)

#### updated code

```
# old style
g = Graph() 
# prepare inputs
g.add_node(LSTM(...))
g.add_node(
    TimeDistributedDense(out_size, activation='softmax'),
    name='h2',
    input='h1'
)
# h2.shape and filter.shape are same. (N, )
g.add_node(
    Activation(activation=normalize,),
    name='action',
    inputs=['h2','filter'], 
    merge_mode='mul', 
    create_output=True
) 
g.compile(...)

# new style
m = Sequential()
m.add(LSTM(...))
m.add(TimeDistributred(Dense(out_size, activation='softmax')))

# how to integrate 'mul merge' and normalization?
m.add_node(BatchNormalization()) # ?
m.compile(...)
```

Comment: First of all, if the reference code uses `Graph()`, then in new Keras, you should be using `Model`. `Merge` in new keras is the same except a few modifications. If you merging two layers, then use `Merge`. If two are tensors, you should use `merge`. See [this](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3921) for more information. I don't see where you need to use masking.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Although I want to merge two tensors, my code doesn't use `Functional API`. Is it possible to use `merge` in my code? Or should I replace my code using `Functional API`?

Comment: Yes. Merging is possible in Sequential. You can use `Merge`. Again, see [this](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3921).